# Excel data-source from text files

Tags: excel

I have multiple reports created from Linux and saved as tabbed text files.  When I open an updated text report in Excel, I find myself doing the same steps over and over again (create table, set filters, pivot, create a chart, etc).

Is there way to create a spreadsheet from a text file, configure it to my liking, and in the future, be able to refresh the data set based on new text file I would provide?  The text file format stays the same and could be tweaked to accommodate Excel.  Ideally, I would prefer to do this without VBA, but that's a minor consideration.

Comment: You can create a "refreshable" table (using your custom format) via `Query Definition`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without VBA I think it's difficult.
You can use something like that:

```
Dim nLast As Integer
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="E:\0\aa.TXT", Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1 _
    , DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False _
    , Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
nLast = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Range("A1:B" & nLast).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Book1.xlsm").Activate
Range("B7").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Open the Txt file, copy and paste only value on your model file (with pivot, chart ...)
The data in my sheet start from B7.